# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function - Dynamically add directives on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to Dynamically add directives on angularjs ?

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. Where I wrong? I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.

I've tried the following, but did not succeed :

```
.directive('addDeleteTemplate', function() {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, $compile) {
                element.on('click', function () {
                    var jQuery = element.parents('tr');
                    var find = jQuery.find('td[class=delete]');
                    var index = $compile('<div delete-news></div>')(scope);// error : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
                    angular.element(find).append(index);
                });
            }
        };
    })



.directive("deleteNews", [
        'NewsApkService', function (NewsApkService) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                templateUrl: getBaseUrl() + 'Templates/News/Delete',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    //element.find('button').bind('click', function (e) {
                    //    
                    //});
                },
                controller: function ($scope, $element, $compile) {

                 }
                }
            }
        }
    ])



 <a  add-delete-template>

 </a>
```

What is this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first directive to this

```
.directive('addDeleteTemplate', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                var jQuery = element.parents('tr');
                var find = jQuery.find('td[class=delete]');
                var index = $compile('<div delete-news></div>')(scope);// error : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
                angular.element(find).append(index);
            });
        }
    };
})
```